# Infinite redirects with Rails config.force_ssl behind a remote SSL proxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, https

I am running a Rails 5.2 app on an Ubuntu VM provided by my organisation. It's served by Nginx (1.14.0) and Passenger (6.0.1).

SSL is provided by the organisation through a load balancer. My app is hosted on myapp1 on the internal network and the organisation provides a public-facing myapp.org.com, which provides SSL to the end user and proxies traffic via HTTP over the internal network to myapp1. I have no control over the load balancer at myapp.org.com.

The app is also served at the /project subdirectory. When I access https://myapp.org.com/, I get a 403 from my Nginx server, as expected (for now). When I access https://myapp.org.com/projects, I get an infinite 301 redirect loop (redirecting to the same URL...).

My Nginx config looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myapp myapp.org.com myapp.organisation.com;
    add_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

    root /var/www;

    location ~ ^/project(/.*|$) {
        # Tell Nginx and Passenger where your app's 'public' directory is
        alias /var/www/project-production/current/public/$1;

        # Turn on Passenger
        passenger_ruby /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@project-production/wrappers/ruby;
        passenger_base_uri /project;
        passenger_app_root /var/www/project-production/current;
        passenger_document_root /var/www/project-production/current/public;
        rails_env production;
        passenger_enabled on;
    }
}
```

And `config/environments/production.rb` contains `config.force_ssl = true`.

In trying to solve this, I also tried using `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;` and no `X-Forwarded-Proto` header at all.

If I set `config.force_ssl = false`, it redirects to http and the organisation's SSO refuses to serve the app.

All of the related posts I can find on SO and around the web talk about using Nginx as a proxy to a local Rails server (like Unicorn or Passenger standalone), but this problem seems to be distinct in that Nginx is serving http requests to a remote SSL-enabled proxy.

Comment: Your question suggests you're running the app locally, however you state you're editing config/environments/production.rb. Are you definitely editing the right environment file?

Comment: I don't know what suggested I'm running it locally but it's definitely the right environment file!

Comment: If you're running the app locally any changes you make to config/environments/production.rb will be ignored. You should be editing config/environments/development.rb, unless you've explicitly set the app to run in production mode on your VM which is unlikely

Comment: Oh, I see. No, the app isn't running locally. The VM is more like a VPS - just the term the org uses :)

Comment: ahh that makes sense

Comment: Sorry for the confusion :). It did make me double-check, though, which is always a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your organizations's load balancer must pass **X-Forwarded-Proto** to your nginx instance. Your application cannot detect its being browsed by a ssl-terminated load balancer. If it doesn't work, you may need to whitelist load balancer's ip inside your application. (i don't know how, i don't code ruby)

Comment: Ah. We used X-Forwarded-Proto on another app served by Apache in a different department but it could be a fluke that that worked. That's also a different version of Rails. What do you mean by "whitelist load balancer's ip"?

Comment: Apache's case maybe a proxy_pass, which the related header is must be added. So thats different story. Some frameworks don't trust every request that says "hey, i came from a ssl-terminated load balancer, here is the related header". Instead, you tell which source(load balancer) application should trust.

Comment: Given what you said about the X-Forwarded-Proto header needing to be added by the remote proxy, I asked the network team about it. Turns out they don't use that header by default but have added it and the address now works as expected! Thank you!